# ANT Migration Tool not pulling correct query fields from Salesforce

Tags: data-loader, data-export, ant-script

I'm using the ANT Migration Tool to obtain a list of all available query fields for several Standard and Custom Objects in my Salesforce environment and I'm running into an issue where the query fields I obtained from the ANT Migration Tool do not completely match the query fields that I would expect to see if I was using the DataLoader WebUI. As a result, I'm not able to use the query fields from ANT to retrieve object data using Data Loader for Windows. How can I obtain the same query fields from ANT that I would get from Data Loader?

Background: The ANT output gets stored in XML format and parsed to create the 'query field' list. More fields are being added that shouldn't be there and I'm not sure how to stop that from happening. I'm following the same flowpath outlined [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool.htm) and [here](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-migration-tool-ant/).

Sample files using the Account sObject:

Build.xml

```
<beans>
    <bean id="AccountExtract"
          class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
          singleton="false">
      <description>AccountExtract job to pull the Account sObject data and export to a CSV file</description>
        <property name="name" value="csvAccountExtract"/>
        <property name="configOverrideMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="false"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="C:\Users\user\Desktop\salesforce_backup\sfdcSoapTrace.log"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://na3.salesforce.com"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.username" value="test-account-username"/>
                <!-- password below has been encrypted using key file, therefore it will not work without the key setting: process.encryptionKeyFile
                the password is not a valid encrypted value, please generate the real value using encrypt.bat utility -->
                <entry key="sfdc.password" value="test-account-password"/>
                <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\conf\key.file"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="600"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="200"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Account"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="500"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select <attributes from ANT Migration Tool> FROM Account"/>
                <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="C:\Users\user\Desktop\salesforce_backup\sf_sobject_account_backup.csv"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    ...
</beans>
```

Data Loader process.bat that calls each bean ID from build.xml

```
call process "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\conf" AccountExtract
call process ...
```

Powershell sample script to call ANT Tool:

```
#Define variables
$ant_directory="C:\Users\user\Desktop\AntCode\ant-salesforce-prgm\"

#Begin ANT extraction
cd $ant_outputdirectory
&ant "retrieveSOQL"

#Begin Data Loader data extraction
start-process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin\process.bat' -Wait
```

List of query fields for Account sObject obtained from ANT Migration Tool that aren't found in Data Loader WebUI:

```
Alfresco_Gateway_Response__c
Billing_Contact_Phone__c
cbit__Clearbit__c
cbit__ClearbitDomain__c
cbit__ClearbitReady__c
cbit__CreatedByClearbit__c
cmis_name__c
cmis_objectId__c
cmis_path__c
Days_Since_Last_Login__c
Days_Since_Previous_Login__c
Last_Login__c
Portal_Inactivity_Alert__c
Previous_Login__c
```

Comment: I am struggling to follow your question. It sounds like you are using Ant to get sObject Describe information and then feeding that into a query in Data Loader. Can you add some specificity on this process and details about which fields do not appear where?

Comment: Sure, please see above fore more details about the process and the fields that consistently do not appear in the standard and custom objects are: CreatedById, CreatedDate, Id, IsDeleted, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, LastReferencedDate, LastViewedDateAccount_Id__c. There are other query fields that also get added when I parse the XML output from ANT Migration Tool that aren't found in the Data Loader WebUI and I suspect those are causing an issue where Data Loader doesn't pull any data at all. Let me know if that makes sense or if you need further clarifying.

Comment: @DavidReed he is using ANT to automate Data Loading. It has nothing to do with Force.com migration tool.

Comment: How do I get the [on hold] tag removed?

Comment: @murkywaters you have to edit your question provide more details use case to get it removed

Comment: Yep, already done.